# Azure DevOps Terraform Init - Remote State - Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, terraform-provider-azure

Experiencing terraform for the very time, I'm following the document from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/automate-terraform?view=azure-devops) to put in my terraform files in a release pipeline that I have with Azure DevOps. Everything runs perfectly fine until the step where it initializes the terraform. It fails with the following error message:

[image]

The storage account itself is provisioned and the key of that also is persisted successfully in the environment variables as per the document.

The YAML I have for `terraform init` in Azure DevOps Release pipeline is:
[image]

And the `terraform` script for the `backend service` is:
[image]

The variables are stored as environment variables inside the release pipeline and there is a `replace token` task that replaces `__` with string empty:
[image]

Her is the step in the pipeline that create the resource group and storage account:
[image]

And finally, the PS scripts that store the storage key in the ENV vars:
[image]

Also, I can't understand why the `get http` from the error message has `env` appended to the `terraform.tformstate`.

I'm running out of ideas why it fails with that exception and what is expecting actually.

I've been Googling around but have been failing so far to resolve the issue. Appreciate your help/thoughts on this.

Comment: Share your Terraform script and where do you deploy the Terraform script? DevOps? give the YAML file.

Comment: added them to the question. Yes, it is Azure DevOps Release pipelines I'm using just per the document link in the question.

Comment: I don't see variables for the storage name and access key, where do you define them?

Comment: they are in the env vars in the release pipeline and there is a powershell script that creates the storage account, reads the key, and persist the key

Comment: Can you share the PowerShell script you use to get the storage account key?

Comment: All things work fine on my side. Do you follow the steps in the article to create the release?

Comment: All the things work fine on my side in the release. Can you check if the value of  `workingDirectory` in the init task is right and make sure the key value is really right.

Comment: yes, I'm following exactly the steps from the link. couldn't find anything wrong with  `workingdirectory`value either. I'm gonna try just the sample from the doc on a new pipeline to see that gives me some leads

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you misspelled storageaccount for your variable.  So the value is not substituted.  You have sotrageaccount.  The t and o are swapped.

Comment: OMG - you're very right. that fixed the problem. thanks Christian.

Comment: Ha! This was the inspiration I too needed to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While Christian Pearce did answer the immediate question, there is underlying problem for this message.
**There is something wrong with your Storage Account settings**

The issue I had was that I placed path information into the Container name

```
- task: TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: Terraform Init
  inputs:
    provider: azurerm
    command: init
    backendServiceArm: [service connection]
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: [resource group]
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: [storage account name]
    backendAzureRmContainerName: [container]/subfolder <-- This is bad and belongs in the Key field
    backendAzureRmKey: ${{ parameters.name }}/${{ parameters.environment }}.tfstate
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Infrastructure
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I got the same error when specifying container name (which was not created yet in the storage account) with the upper case which turned out not to be allowed in Azure Storage.